# How the achieve desugaring in android gradle builds?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm developing an app that needs to run on phones with Android API 19+. In talks with management to see if we can drop support for older versions of Android, but it seems almost certain we can't live with 26+ only.

Recently there has appeared a need to use a library that uses some Java 1.8 features, and those fail to dex.

I had previously thought that automatic "desugaring" had been enabled when building/dexing with gradle for a while now, and issues like these would be "automagically" solved by converting the unsupported-in-1.7 opcodes to functionally equivalent 1.7 opcode blobs.

But my builds are failing with
"Private interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24)"
and similar error messages (as I said, API level 26 is the largest on I see), and:

```
"Failed to transform artifact '...' to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=false, dexing-is-debuggable=false, dexing-min-sdk=1}"
```

As you can see, dexing seems to be happening with "dexing-enable-desugaring=false" and "dexing-min-sdk=1", and I'd like to change those. I've been searching for a way to set those for quite a while now, and can't seem to find a way to tell gradle to pass the right parameters to the dexer.

Here are the relevant snippets of configuration files:

gradle.properties:

```
androidBuildToolsVersion=28.0.3
androidCompileSdkVersion=28
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.60'
    compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.60'
    ...
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    compileSdkVersion androidCompileSdkVersion.toInteger()

    buildToolsVersion androidBuildToolsVersion

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            ...
       }
    }

    defaultConfig.applicationId = "..."
}
```

Any suggestions?

Also, worth noting, this is not a "pure" android / Gradle project, there is native code involved, and a build system that I don't have good control over, that runs Gradle as a step in the build process. If there are multiple ways to configure the dexer parameters, I'd prefer something that requires modifying build.gradle, as that is the only thing I have direct control over, inserting something into gradle.properties would require hacking the build system in ways I'd rather avoid, but I'll take it if that's the only way to do it.